# How to broadcast an action to another application's BroadcastReceiver in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

As of android API 26 (android 8.0) android is limiting access to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` which is mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)).
So in order to send a broadcast at a specific time by using `PendingIntent`, I have to specify the receiver component's name in `Intent`.

But when I do not know that any app is hosting a receiver,
**is there any way sending broadcasts to another application's broadcast receiver?**

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of test in order to create a broadcast which will target any application that receives the action. Here is the result:

**You only will be able to target only one class of only one application!**

You can easily target a class inside an application like this:

```kotlin
val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    Intent().apply {
        action = "SOME_ACTION_TO_BROADCAST"
        component = ComponentName("PACKAGE_NAME_OF_TARGET_APPLICATION", "TARGET_CLASS_PACKAGE.<ClassName>")

        val pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, this, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
            
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, /* any time in future */ System.currentTimeMillis() + 5_000, pi)
}
```